# What are the typical ways to cache the result of a relational database query using Redis?

Tags: caching, redis

What do developers commonly use as the key and value to cache the result from a SQL query into Redis? For example, if I have a Users table, and I want to cache the results from the query:

```
SELECT name, age FROM Users
```

1) Which Redis data structure should I use? Should I just have a single Key for the query and store the entire object returned by the database as the Value as such:

{ key: { object returned by database } }

Or should I use Redis' List data structure and loop through the rows individually and push them into the List as such:

{ key: [ ... ]}

Wouldn't this add computation time of O(N)? How is this more effective than just simply storing the object returned by the database?

Or should I use Redis' Hash Map data structure and loop through the rows individually and set a unique Key for each row with its corresponding attributes as such:

{ key1: {name: 'Bob', age: 25} }, { key2: {name: 'Sally', age: 15} }, ...

2) What would be a good rule of thumb with regards to the Key? From my understanding, some people just use the SQL query as the Key? But if you do so, does that mean you would have to store the entire object returned by the database as the Value (as per question 1)? Is this the best way to do it? If you are using an ORM, do you still use the SQL query as the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nicely analyzed in the [Database Caching Strategies Using Redis whitepaper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/database-caching-strategies-using-redis/welcome.html), by AWS.

Here the options discussed in the document. What is best is really a design decision based on tradeoffs you have to make for your specific use-case.

> **Cache the Database SQL ResultSet**
>
> Cache a serialized ResultSet object that contains the fetched database
> row.
>
> - **Pro**: When data retrieval logic is abstracted (e.g., as in a Data Access Object or DAO layer), the consuming code expects only a
>   ResultSet object and does not need to be made aware of its
>   origination. A ResultSet object can be iterated over, regardless of
>   whether it originated from the database or was deserialized from the
>   cache, which greatly reduces integration logic. This pattern can be
>   applied to any relational database.
> - **Con**: Data retrieval still requires extracting values from the ResultSet object cursor and does not further simplify data access; it
>   only reduces data retrieval latency.
>
> **Cache Select Fields and Values in a Custom Format**
>
> Cache a subset of a fetched database row into a custom structure that
> can be consumed by your applications.
>
> - **Pro**: This approach is easy to implement. You essentially store specific retrieved fields and values into a structure such as JSON or
>   XML and then SET that structure into a Redis string. The format you
>   choose should be something that conforms to your application’s data
>   access pattern.
> - **Con**: Your application is using different types of objects when querying for particular data (e.g., Redis string and database
>   results). In addition, you are required to parse through the entire
>   structure to retrieve the individual attributes associated with it.
>
> **Cache Select Fields and Values into an Aggregate Redis Data Structure**
>
> Cache the fetched database row into a specific data structure that can
> simplify the application’s data access.
>
> - **Pro**: When converting the ResultSet object into a format that simplifies access, such as a Redis Hash, your application is able to
>   use that data more effectively. This technique simplifies your data
>   access pattern by reducing the need to iterate over a ResultSet object
>   or by parsing a structure like a JSON object stored in a string. In
>   addition, working with aggregate data structures, such as Redis Lists,
>   Sets, and Hashes provide various attribute level commands associated
>   with setting and getting data, eliminating the overhead associated
>   with processing the data before being able to leverage it.
> - **Con**: Your application is using different types of objects when querying for particular data (e.g., Redis Hash and database results).
>
> **Cache Serialized Application Object Entities**
>
> Cache a subset of a fetched database row into a custom structure that
> can be consumed by your applications.
>
> - **Pro**: Use application objects in their native application state with    simple serializing and deserializing techniques. This can
>   rapidly accelerate application performance by minimizing data
>   transformation logic.
> - **Con**: Advanced application development use case

Regarding 2)

> What would be a good rule of thumb with regards to the Key?

Using the SQL query as the Key is OK for as long as you are sure it is unique. Add prefixes if there is a risk of not-uniqueness. You may have other databases with the same table names, leading to the same queries. Also make them invariant: all lower case or upper case. Redis keys are case-sensitive.

> But if you do so, does that mean you would have to store the entire object returned by the database as the Value (as per question 1)?

Not necessarily, it comes down to what processing you are doing with the query. Chances are some are best stored as raw entire object for processing, some as JSON-stringified object to return quickly to the client, some as rows, etc. The best is to adapt accordingly.

> Is this the best way to do it?

Not necessarily.

> If you are using an ORM, do you still use the SQL query as the key?

You may if your ORM easily exposes the SQL Query programmatically, and it is consistent.

I wouldn't get fixed on the idea of using the SQL Query as key, use something you can be sure it is consistent, it will optimize your processing, and you'll have clear rules to invalidate. It could be the method call with parameters, the web API call, etc.